# Issue in echo statement in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have a very peculiar issue with a script that I have wrote today. I am trying to form an ip address from two variables namely url and port. I am getting the url value from a library script which echos 10.241.1.8 and the port number is 10000. Now if I concatenate both the url and the port into another variable ip, I get completely a strange result(:10000241.1.8). I have my code and its result below. Please help me with your suggestions to fix this.

```
clear
echo $(date +'%H:%M:%S')'>> "Sample Records" Script started...'
usage() {
  echo ">> $ script.sh -ctoff 89 -env c -ns reporting -depPath /user/release/audit_prime_oozie"
  echo "Usage: $ script.sh -ctoff <Cutoff number> -env <testing cluster. ex: s for staging,c,d,p and a> -ns <optional: hive namespace> -depPath <deployment path>" 
}

# Function to validate if value of a parameter is not empty 
validate () {
if  [[ $flag != 1 ]]; then
  if [[ $tmpVar == *"-"* ]] || [[ -z $tmpVar ]]; then
    usage
    exit 1
  fi
fi
}

options=$@
if [[ -z $options ]]; then
usage
exit 1
fi
arguments=($options)
index=0

# Function to extract the parameter values
check (){
for x in $options
  do
    index=`expr $index + 1`
     case $x in
      -ctoff)
      cutOff="${arguments[index]}"
      tmpVar=$cutOff
      validate $tmpVar
      ;;
      -env)
      env="${arguments[index]}"
      tmpVar=$env
      validate $tmpVar
      ;;
      -ns)
      ns="${arguments[index]}"
      tmpVar=$ns
      validate $tmpVar
      ;;
      -depPath)
      depPath="${arguments[index]}"
      tmpVar=$depPath
      validate $tmpVar
      ;;
     esac

     if [[ -z $ns ]];then
        ns=reporting
     fi
  done
}

check $@

error_exit(){
  echo "$1" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

# Create the execution directory
user=$(id -u -n)
PWD=`pwd`
INSTALL_ROOT=$PWD
LOCAL_DIR="/tmp/$user/sample_duns"
if [[ ! -d $LOCAL_DIR ]]; then
  mkdir -p $LOCAL_DIR
  echo ">> Created local directory $LOCAL_DIR"
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo ">> Unable to create $LOCAL_DIR, writing to current folder $INSTALL_ROOT"
    LOCAL_DIR=$INSTALL_ROOT
  fi
fi
if [[ $(ls -A $LOCAL_DIR) ]]; then
  echo ">> Removed the temp files from $LOCAL_DIR"
  rm -r $LOCAL_DIR/*
fi

# create the file name
datestamp=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H')
outFile=sample_duns_$datestamp.txt

# Copy the contents from HDFS to Local directory
echo ">> Copying required files from HDFS"
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal $depPath/data-warehouse/config/server.properties $LOCAL_DIR || error_exit "Cannot copy files from HDFS! Exiting now.."
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal $depPath/data-warehouse/reporting/lib_getHiveServer2ip.sh $LOCAL_DIR || error_exit "Cannot copy files from HDFS! Exiting now.."
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo ">> Files missing. Exiting now.."
  exit 1
fi

# Call the lib script to get appropriate hiveserver2 ip address from the supplied environment for beeline execution 
echo ">> Reading the HiveServer2 ip"
chmod +x $LOCAL_DIR/lib_getHiveServer2ip.sh
url=$($LOCAL_DIR/lib_getHiveServer2ip.sh $env $LOCAL_DIR/server.properties)
echo url=$url
port=10000
echo ip=$url:$b
```

Here is my output from the terminal.

```
11:18:16>> "Sample Records" Script started...
>> Removed the temp files from /tmp/user/sample_duns
>> Copying required files from HDFS
>> Reading the HiveServer2 ip
url=10.241.1.8
:10000241.1.8
```

I am expecting the below result

```
ip=10.241.1.8:10000
```

Adding the lib_getHiveServer2ip.sh script below

```
. $2 # read properties file

if [[ $1 == "d" ]]; then
  ip=$devHSer
elif [[ $1 == "c" ]]; then
  ip=$crankHSer
elif [[ $1 == "s" ]]; then
  ip=$stgHSer
elif [[ $1 == "p" ]]; then
  ip=$prdHSer
elif [[ $1 == "a" ]]; then
  ip=$alpHSer
else
  echo ">> Invalid cluster ip encountered. Exiting now ..."
  exit 1
fi
echo $ip
```

Comment: Just a terminology note: `10.241.1.8` *is* an IP address; the combination of an IP address and a port `10.241.1.8:10000`, doesn't really have a standard name, as it combines values used by two different protocols (the address is used by IP, the port by TCP or UDP). You might refer to it as a connection endpoint.

Comment: The first block of code is mostly irrelevant, only the last 7 lines matter.  The last line `echo ip=$url:$b ` references **$b**, but **$b** was not initialized in any of the code shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `url` variable contains a carriage return character for some reason. Check `lib_getHiveServer2ip.sh` for weirdness.

Pipe your `echo` output to `hexdump` to confirm.

Edit: looks like your properties file has bad line endings. Use the `file` utility to check.

Comment: Do you know what type of carriage return does it have?

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy, please use `hexdump`.  `hexdump` shows the type of [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: With the input from @Carl Norum I was able to find the carriage return '\r' in the url variable. I have included the below code to remove the carriage return.

`url=$( echo $url | tr -d '\r')`